# ListView button click toast textview text

Tags: android, listview, android-button

I am having a listview with buttons and I am trying to toast a text which will be the text of the textview with the id mobile when the user click on the button 
of the list item.
My view class is as below and when I click on the button app closes ans restarts.

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);
        holder.imageview = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.photo);
        holder.tvName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.doctor);
        holder.tvMobile = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.mobile);

        Button btnCall = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnCall);
        btnCall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String message= ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile)).getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }

    holder.imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.noimage);
    new DownloadImageTask(holder.imageview).execute(doctorList.get(position).getImage());
    holder.tvName.setText(doctorList.get(position).getName());
    holder.tvMobile.setText(doctorList.get(position).getMobile());
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your crash log?

Comment: Try replacing `((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile)).getText().toString()` with `holder.tvMobile.getText().toString()`

Comment: yeah! please share the error log

Comment: It worked but when the button clicks,it always shows the last list item mobile, not he current button one. @PrerakSola

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong:-

instead of:-

```
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
                String message= ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile)).getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
```

you need to do

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String message= ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.mobile).getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Because you mobile text view is not a child of clicked button and you are trying to get his reference from the button which is wrong.